# Ionic 3 Local Notification pushes into a specific page too many times

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm new on Ionic and I may have miss some important detail developing a simple app that should show a specific page trough opening a Local Notification. The issue is:I have made a button that generate a Local notification by clicking on it. If I generate the notification for the first time and then I click on it, it works like a charm, but when I generate the second notification if I click on it the app pushes the new page two times, the third time it pushes three times an so on, even if I go back to the root page through the navigation bar.

Someone can help me understand what I'm doing wrong? 
Thank you so much

This is the code for the root page

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Page2Page } from '../page2/page2';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private localNotifications: LocalNotifications, public platform: Platform) {

  }

  click(){

      this.platform.ready().then(()=>{

        this.localNotifications.schedule({
          id: 1 ,
          title: 'Notifica',
          text: 'Single ILocalNotification',

        })

        this.localNotifications.on('click').subscribe(()=>{

          console.log("Notification Subscribed")
          this.navCtrl.push(Page2Page);

        })
      })
  }

}
```

And this is the second page (it literally does nothing)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

/**
 * Generated class for the Page2Page page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-page2',
  templateUrl: 'page2.html',
})
export class Page2Page {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Page2Page');
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you only need an if condition simply and the page will not be routed.. i.e like this **if (this.app.getActiveNav().getViews()[0].name != "Page2Page") than open the Page2Page else do nothing**. Inform me if this solution works.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. The previous answer is right I have to subscribe just one time, but first I have to check if the platform is ready otherwise cordova gives me an error and the app wont work.

This is the code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Page2Page } from '../page2/page2';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    private localNotifications: LocalNotifications,
    public platform: Platform) {

      this.platform.ready().then(()=>{

        this.localNotifications.on('click').subscribe(()=>{

        console.log("Notification Subscribed")
        this.navCtrl.push(Page2Page);

        })
      })
  }


  click(){

      this.platform.ready().then(()=>{

        this.localNotifications.schedule({
          id: 1 ,
          title: 'Notifica',
          text: 'Single ILocalNotification',

        })
      })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are subscribing to an event each time you click. When you subscribe you don't override and previous subscription. You either need to remove the previous subscription or not subscribe each click. Try the following.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Page2Page } from '../page2/page2';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private localNotifications: LocalNotifications, public platform: Platform) {
        this.localNotifications.on('click').subscribe(()=>{

          console.log("Notification Subscribed")
          this.navCtrl.push(Page2Page);

        })
  }

  click(){

      this.platform.ready().then(()=>{

        this.localNotifications.schedule({
          id: 1 ,
          title: 'Notifica',
          text: 'Single ILocalNotification',

        })


      })
  }

}
```

I have moved the subscription for the localNotifications to the constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but adding the subscription in the constructor didn't work.. When I launch the app in the iOS emulator it doesn't show anything :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, it's work like a charm.

```
      createLocalNotification(options: any) {
        // Schedule a single notification
        this.localNotifications.schedule(options);
        // Subscribe to onClick event
        let observable = this.localNotifications.on('click').subscribe((data) => {
          this.navCtrl.push(Page2Page);
          // Unsubscribe to OnClick event after push your page
          observable.unsubscribe();
        });
      }
```